# How to get all date value in one column by array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql-9.2

I have a table named 'mtn_name' like --

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Body Repair |
| 1 | Gear Repair |
| 1 | Gear oil change |
| 2 | Body glass Repair |
| 2 | Gearbox Repair |
| 2 | Oil change |

Requirement query result is like

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Body Repair,Gear Repair,Gear oil change |
| 2 | Body glass Repair,Gearbox Repair,Oil change |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string_agg, it will group the string which you need.
Example :

```
select id,string_agg(Value,',' ORDER BY Value) As group_value 
from mtn_name 
group by id
```